# jQuery: select one specific element from clicked SVG group

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

So, I have a simple SVG group:

```
<g id="interceptor">
    <ellipse cx="0" cy="15" rx="6" ry="14" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
    <polygon points="0,-20 7,10 0,0 -7,10" fill="blue"/>
    <polygon points="0,-20 7,10 0,0" fill="darkblue"/>
</g>
```

Which I then use like this:

```
<g class="ship" id="ship3" transform="rotate(-180,480,24) translate(480,24)">
   <use xlink:href="#interceptor"/>
</g>
```

Now, what I would like to do is to add a stroke around the first polygon from the group when the whole group is clicked, but I don't know how to access contents of the interceptor group via jQuery. I was thinking about something like this, but contents() returns nothing:

```
$(".ship").click(function() {
    $(this).find("use").contents().find("polygon").first().attr({"stroke-width":1, stroke:"white"});
});
```

I can, of course, add a stroke around the entire ".ship" and it works, but it's not what I want because this creates strokes between polygons in the group. Additionally, there can be a number of separate objects that use the #interceptor group, and only the one that is actually clicked should get the stroke. Is that doable?

Comment: You'd find this much easier if you stopped using <use> elements and just used the elements you want directly.

Comment: Yes, but like I said, I may need to re-use the #interceptor group many times. I'd rather not define it anew every time.

Comment: so each time you change the stroke you need all instances of the <use> element to update? Anyway if you do <use> has no contents() you'll have to follow it's xlink:href to find the element it points to.

Comment: It would be easier to just have two versions of the interceptor, one with the stroke and one without and then switch them out on click eg: `$(this).find('use').attr('xlink:href', '#interceptorWithStroke');`